# PyQt4 Vertical Layout Autospacing

Tags: python, layout, pyqt4, qt-designer, groupbox

I am using Qt Designer to set up a simple gui for a program I am writing in which I need to display a column of radio buttons.  I want to hide some of the radio buttons (not just disable them) based on whether or not their corresponding port is currently available.  The radio buttons are in a group box with a vertical layout, so whenever I hide one of them, the rest of the buttons move apart to fill the space.

Is there any way to make it so the buttons will compress towards top of the groupbox instead of autospacing themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a vertical spacer below the bottom-most radio button.